# how do I determine the specific instanceId for a given report

Tags: reports

How do I determine the instanceId for a given report? The dropdown on the access panel gives me a subset of all reports, but I can't figure out how to get the id for other reports for email automation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Its quite simple to get the Instance ID for a report through its URL. Consider an example of Contribution Summary report, the url for it is `civicrm/report/instance/7?force=1&reset=1` So the instance id in this case will **7** i.e integer value anything after `civicrm/report/instance/` will be your instance id or you can use api explorer to get the instance ID.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you everyone. Used and now working. Appreciated.